# How to read excel file in python and rewrite it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I have an Excel sheet full of addresses and base on these addresses (the postal code), determine whether they belong to North/South/East/West region.

[image]

An example of how an address looks:

*164 Penang Road, 01-05, **238464***

238463 being the postal code, and how North/South/East/West region is determined is base on the first 2 numbers '23'.

This is my current code:

```
import xlrd

loc = ("C:\\Users\Desktop\Windflower\\address.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
   print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
```

How do I go about coding a program which reads only the first 2 numbers of the postal code and determines which region it belongs to?

So my output would be placed into a new excel sheet:
[image]

I just started coding and I've read that you can do an if/else method but so far I'm getting errors.

Comment: I think you need to focus your question. First of all what it is actually about? A way to get the north/east... or a way to create new excel sheet? Also, how are we supposed to know the logic of determining what area each zipcode is? And lastly, according to your output image it seems you just need to add a new column, not a sheet

Comment: yes i want to add a new column in the sheet, how do i do that? i already figured out the logic of determining which zipcode = which region, how do i insert it in a new column in the existing excel sheet i already have?

Comment: well, you can't do that with `xlrd`. Either use `openpyxl` or `pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your codestyle you can try this

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    address = sheet.cell_value(i,0)
    address = address.rstrip() #to remove trailing spaces if any
    zip = address[-6:-4]  #to get the first two digits of zip
```

Comment: why `zip = address[-6:-4]`? why not just `zip = address[:2]`?

Comment: Because address contains whole address in the cell not just the zipcode.

Comment: how do i insert the regions (NSEW) in a new column in the existing excel sheet i already have?

Comment: @KapilKumar yes but it seems weird to slice from the end when you want the first 2 characters. Taking the first 2 characters is canonically done by `[:2]`

Comment: well we can do that if we add a line  `zip= address.split()[-1]`. And now we can do  `zip = zip[:2]`.